# android studio: change variable generation behaviour

Tags: android, android-studio

By default, when, for example, extracting a local variable from an expression like `o.getSomeMember()`, it generates a default variable name `someMember`. I'd rather it generated the default variable name `sm`.

The same thing happens when creating a new object and assigning it to a new local variable. For example, if on a new line you type `SomeClass<space>` then ctrl-space, it makes a default variable that looks like `someClass`, but I'd rather it made a variable that looked like `sc`.

Is there a way of customising this variable generation process?

Comment: Go to File > Settings > Editor > Java > Code Generation. In the Naming section, uncheck the box "Prefer longer names" and see if that does what you want.

Comment: I already tried that. No change.